# How do I download a webpage over http using visual basic?

Tags: vb.net

I wrote the following code to download webpages from sites that use SSL:

```
 Public Function DownloadFileUsingSSL(ByVal URLstring As String, ByVal descFilePathAndName As String, ByRef errorMessage As String) As Boolean
        Dim wc As WebClient

    Try
        wc = New WebClient()
        wc.Headers.Add("cookie", "")
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls
        wc.DownloadFile(URLstring, descFilePathAndName)
    Catch ex As Exception
        errorMessage = ex.Message
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

The problem is doesn't work, at least when I tried it on:

https://www.americanthinker.com/blog/2020/09/joe_biden_caught_on_tape_abusing_americas_troops.html

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Some web sites give back compressed streams even if you didn't ask for it (adding an `Accept-Encoding` header). When this happens, you can see the compression method in the `content-encoding` header of the underlying WebResponse (or the corresponding value in the WebClient's `ResponseHeaders` property).

Comment: To avoid this (and other) kind of quirks related to WebClient (as the botched Encoding), use HttpClient instead. Decompression, if any, is automatic. Note that setting the `SecurityProtocol` is only useful in Window 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2. Avoid in Windows 8.1+